# Une chronologie douteuse?

Tags: figure-de-style, style-de-rédaction

À propos de l’entrée de Victor Hugo à l’Académie française en 1841, dont les circonstances sont relatées ainsi dans *Le Salon des Immortels — Une académie très française* (publié en 2002) de Louis-Bernard Robitaille, journaliste canadien correspondant à Paris pendant plus de trente ans pour des publications québécoises connues, et résident de Paris depuis 1972 :

> Une caricature du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle montre un Victor Hugo géant campé sur les piliers du pouvoir à Paris : l’Assemblée nationale d’un côté, l’Académie de l’autre. Pour les journaux de l’époque, il s’agissait d’une affaire d’État. Et pourquoi donc ? Parce que l’élection de Voltaire en avait été une en 1746, **et que celle de Charles Maurras le serait également en 1938**. Parce que, dès les origines mêmes, on le verra, l’Académie avait été sans raison apparente une affaire d’État majeure.

Il y a dans la section mise en gras, tout au moins au premier degré, une indifférence frappante pour la chronologie : on ne réagit pas d’une manière donnée parce d’autres le feront identiquement cent ans plus tard.

- Je ne crois pas que l’on puisse ici parler exactement d’**anachronisme**, mais je pourrais accepter que c’en soit une forme particulière. Mais peu importe la filiation. J’aimerais connaître le nom particulier de cette figure de style.
- Je n’aime pas vraiment la tournure utilisée, elle ne me fait pas sourire et me semble maladroite, mais c’est une opinion personnelle, et donc pas tout à fait dans le registre de ce site de questions et réponses. Je contourne le problème en demandant si la technique a souvent, ou parfois, été utilisée, que ce soit en littérature ou en journalisme, et plus particulièrement dans les cas où l’humour n’est pas forcément le moteur principal de la communication. Une illustration par des exemples serait souhaitée (si toutefois il y en a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je n'y vois pas la même chose que toi, pour moi ça n'a pas vraiment de rapport avec la chronologie.

Le *parce que* est maladroit/figuré, parce qu'il ne désigne pas la cause, mais une conséquence commune à tous les autres cas, invariable.

Ex:

> -Prends le train ! Si tu prends la voiture, tu vas être en retard !
>
> -Pourquoi ?
>
> -*Parce qu'à chaque fois que tu prends la voiture, t'es en retard* ! Parce que tu peux pas t'empêcher de passer par des petites routes, de regarder le paysage, et t'arrives 2 heures après tout le monde !

De mon point de vue, c'est essentiellement la même chose. Il n'y a pas la chronologie postérieure pour justifier l'évènement, mais on a bien le premier "*parce que*" qui ne répond pas à "*pourquoi tu seras en retard*" mais à l'affirmation "*pourquoi je sais que tu vas être en retard*".

Dans la phrase avec Hugo, même si l'auteur "triche" en écrivant après les faits, il le dit comme si "On aurait pu prévoir que ce serait une affaire d'état", avec pour raison : "C'est toujours comme ça".

Le fait de prendre un évènement postérieur renforce juste l'idée du "*Ça a toujours été comme ça et ça sera toujours comme ça, avant ou après Hugo.*"

Comment: «—Pourquoi allais-je être en retard en prenant mon auto plutôt que le train la semaine dernière? —Parce que ça t’arrive toujours! Parce que hier tu as pris ton auto et tu as été en retard!» «Parce que c’est une vérité éternelle de cette relation qu’entretiennent les journaux avec l’Académie». Sûrement l'auteur avait en tête quelque chose dans cette lignée, mais l'effet ne me semble pas très réussi, ce que vous mentionnez aussi en décrivant le *parce que* comme maladroit. Merci de votre réponse détaillée.

Comment: ce n'est pas vraiment maladroit, juste une figure de style un peu zarbi (oh, pardonnez le verlan) mais parfaitement honorable bien qu'un peu capilotractée. Cependant j'aurais écrit : «  Parce que l’élection de Voltaire en avait été une en 1746, [sous-entendu : d'ailleurs] celle de Charles Maurras le serait également en 1938 ». Ça n'aurait pas dressé le poil de certains, à juste titre, une sorte de futur dans le passé tout à fait acceptable. Bon, enfin, ce que j'en dit …

Answer (score 5):

> J’aimerais connaître le nom particulier de cette figure de style.

On pourrait la qualifier de sorte d'[**extrapolation**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/extrapolation).

N'ayant, je le confesse, lu ni le livre ni l'auteur en question, je suis mal placé pour approfondir l'analyse.

En revanche, à propos de la caricature décrite dans l'extrait, on peut supposer qu'il s'agit de [la suivante, de Benjamin Roubaud](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Pantheon_charivarique.jpg?uselang=fr) :

[image]

On y retrouve bien l'Académie française, mais l'autre monument foulé par Victor Hugo est le Théâtre français, pas l'Assemblée nationale. Peut-être est-ce une autre extrapolation...

Dans le texte accompagnant la caricature, il est écrit,

> ...
>   Il est grand, il est grand, mes frères,
>   Il a sous ses pieds les palais,
>   À ses genoux, les ministères,
>   ...

qui colle bien avec l'idée de pouvoir présente dans le texte de Robitaille.

Comment: Pourquoi une extrapolation sert-elle de justification? Ou alors, où se passe la transition, dans le texte, entre le moment où l'auteur justifie et celui où il extrapole vers un futur (avéré depuis)?

Comment: L'auteur extrapole les deux affaires d'état connues au moment de la narration à une affaire d'état «hypothétique» (donc évoquée au conditionnel comme l'a justement souligné aCOSwt) mais qui est avérée et peut donc servir la justification. La formule est équivalente à *comme celle de Charles Maurras le sera également en 1938*. Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de composante humoristique.

Comment: Humoristique ? Non! Bien d'accord avec vous. **Sarcastique**... en revanche... n'en doutez pas! Ou... si vous persistez... ce qui est votre droit le plus strict. alors... lisez le livre dans son entier et/ou... celui... d'**Henri**!

Comment: Je veux dire... heuu... en fait c'est insister que je veux dire : Je **crois** que nous sommes à des années lumières d'un **besoin** de **justification**. Quiconque aura lu cet auteur sera convaincu, sera absolument **sûr a priori** qu'il... n'en a et absolument **nul** besoin! Comment qu'il dirait Coluche ? "Le français, je le parle très mieux qu'vous et je vous... ?"

Comment: @aCOSwt Moi, lire un livre dans son entier ? Tu n'y penses pas ! ;-) Il semble y avoir un malentendu. Il me semble que Montée de lait ne parlait pas de justification grammaticale de la figure de rhétorique, mais de justification logique du raisonnement (parce que). À part ça, je me demande de quelle caricature il s'agit. J'ai trouvé celle-là: https://www.revuedesdeuxmondes.fr/victor-hugo-dents-de-caricature/benjamin-roubaud-la-caricature/ mais les monuments représentés sont le Théâtre français (pas l'Assemblée nationale donc) et l'Académie française.

Comment: **Tout** mis de coté. Et, nous exprimant aujourd'hui. C'est à dire... plus... facilement... c'est bien à dire... en toute connaissance des (d)ébats contemporains... (qui avaient déjà lieu, mais de façon bien plus discrète et sçavante aux temps de l'édition du livre en question)... sans dec... jlliagre... vous vous sentiriez, vous, d'écrire sur Maurras autrement qu'au second degré ? Bha! PasMoi!

Comment: Je veux dire encore par rapport au comment ci-dessus : D'autres **Justifications** et **par moins** contrevers-*ables*... il pouvait, en tant que justifications, en trouver... hmmm... 2 ou 3!... facilement!

Comment: L'auteur aurait alors servi cela, comme il le fait pour Voltaire,  d'un bon vieil indicatif des familles! On ne se sert pas d'un conditionnel pour justifier... que je sais.

Comment: Belle trouvaille que la caricature. Je ne sais pas si c'est bien celle dont il était question, mais ça colle presque, à l'exception que vous mentionnez près... Une belle enquête que je vous prie humblement d'ajouter à votre réponse, en dépit de mon vote qui vous est désormais acquis.

Comment: C'est fait. P.S. : Souffrez qu'on se tutoie...

Comment: Pour la caricature, pourrait-on dire qu’il s’agit d’une [licence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/licence) ou d’une liberté, en plus d’une extrapolation?

Comment: On pourrait dire que l'auteur *s'est permis une petite liberté avec le dessin*. C'est peut-être simplement une faute d'inattention mais elle est de toute façon sans conséquence.

Answer (score 2):

Il ne faut pas voir dans cette exemplification la recherche de la démonstration d'une cause à effet; c'est une pratique assez courante d'introduire ces sortes d'exemples qui tendent à donner une occurrence de plus d'un procédé connu par la locution conjonctive « parce que ».
Il s'agit du sens sens « B », second cas dans le TLFi;

> B. Fam. [La prop. introd. par parce que sert à justifier le dire; elle porte sur l'énonciation]
>   [Sert à justifier une affirmation]

On pourrait, à la place de « parce que » utiliser « pour la même raison que ». En effet, l'emploi de cette dernière locution pourrait être préférée par de nombreux lecteurs et écrivains.

Comment: Et quel est le rôle de la question introduisant cette réponse *(Et pourquoi donc?)*?

Comment: @Montéedelait Il me semble que cette question s'interprète presque exactement  comme « Et pour quelle raison donc? ». On y répond par «Pour la raison que l’élection de Voltaire en avait été une en 1746, et que celle de Charles Maurras le serait également en 1938. Pour la raison  que, dès les origines mêmes, on le verra, l’Académie avait été sans raison apparente une affaire d’État majeure.».

Comment: Il me semble que le contexte ne se prête pas exactement à cette lecture que vous proposez. J'y vois que l'auteur se place momentanément au XIXe siècle, et invoque le XXe pour justifier ce qui s'y passe. Je serais heureux de lire votre interprétation complète de l'extrait, d'une manière qui justifiât votre compréhension de l'extrait particulier.

Comment: @Montéedelait Justement, il s'agit d'une justification, mais pas selon la démonstration d'une cause à effet; il ne s'agit de rien de plus que de montrer que la raison est un phénomène bien établi qui opère à travers les âges et pour cela, sans la nommer, on donne, à travers les âges (l'auteur remonte aussi au XIIXe siècle) des cas dont elle été l'agent caractérisé de l'effet (être une affaire d'état); néanmoins, un examen plus approfondi de la question ne devrait pas être négligé.

Answer (score 1):

Dit brutalement, c'est à dire, sans prendre en compte le style d'un auteur qui n'en est pas dénué ni sa propension (charmante) à charger le niveau implicite.

Je ne vois ici qu'un bien ordinaire ***hétérochronisme***. Ordinaire chez ceux qui... racontent l'Histoire. Vous cherchez d'autres cas de ce genre ? Prenez le premier bouquin d'Histoire venu et... vous n'aurez pas à passer beaucoup de pages.
Est-il possible de raconter l'Histoire sans hétérochronisme ?
Pour ma part, je rejoindrai [Frédéric Duval](https://journals.openedition.org/anabases/75).

Ce qui **m**'interpelle, **moi**, dans cette phrase est que cet hétérochronisme, tout en étant, et en tant que tel, très **explicitement assumé** par l'auteur avec la mention de la date (le lecteur n'en avait pas besoin pour savoir que Maurras est postérieur à VH) est servi par... un **conditionnel**!... quand... partout ailleurs, nous restons dans l'indicatif...
L'historien (que je ne suis pas) met un indicatif futur sans hésitation!

=> aCOSwt! RED ALERT! DEFCON 2! L'auteur sait tout cela très mieux que moi... => Charge au second degré! <sup>1</sup>

Laquelle ? Héhé... à vous de la dire!... C'est... un (le?) jeu!

Bon... allez!... En finale... cela ne vous plaît pas... je peux vous comprendre! En nos temps de PC... la charge au second degré est rarement positive... surtout chez un amateur de... sarcasmes que j'en profite pour ici, et en cela, saluer!

<sub>1 NDaCOSwt : Note bien que j'y vais facile là... le titre avait à lui seul déjà déclenché DEFCON 1!... ;-)</sub>

Comment: Merci pour le lien, très intéressant, et le doigt pointé vers ce conditionnel, qui détonne en effet sur le reste du texte et qui m'avait échappé. Je ne suis pas encore convaincu, cependant, que le tour ne soit qu'un simple anachronisme et c'est tout. Il me semble encore y voir la volonté directe de l'auteur de nous lancer à la figure une aberration pour faire sourire, bien que j'en sois, avec les deux premières réponses, un peu moins convaincu qu'avant.

Comment: @Montéedelait : J'ai déjà eu l'occasion ici de vous faire part de ma **croyance** qu'un *bon auteur*, dans un livre pourtant accessible à **tous**, un texte de loi auquel vous pouvez être soumis **en général** ne s'**adresse**, ni systématiquement, ni partout, à **vous en particulier** https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86119/discussion-between-nonobstant-fascisme-and-montee-de-lait.  Et, tout particulièrement pour ce qui concerne l'**implicite**... suiteensuite...

Comment: @Montéedelait :  Je me vois contraint **ici**, dans certaines de mes notes à vocation sarcastique, de les terminer par un QHAAA! abrégeant un *Qui habet aures audiendi audiat*. Le titre choisi par l'auteur me semble ici suffisamment éloquent... certains des implicites seront de toute évidence destinés à certains... pris en particulier. Je ne **crois** pas que, dans le cas qui vous préoccupe ici, ce soit à **vos** oreilles que l'auteur s'adresse... et... je **crois** encore... que ceci n'est pas destiné à être entendu par ces oreilles dans l'intention de... les faire sourire...

Comment: @Montéedelait : Après, moi, pour autant que je suis, le sarcasme au second degré... même gratuit ça me fait me marrer. Toujours! et Gratuitement! J'aime... par principe!

Comment: Je trouve tant mieux que vous en sourissiez (un petit imparfait du subjonctif par jour éloigne le docteur pour toujours, comme nous le disons si bien, nous les franglais d'America (par principe, aussi)). Pour moi, je trouve la ficelle un peu grosse, comme le disait le premier rang au théâtre de marionnettes de mes jeunes années (du temps où ça nous amusait...)

Comment: Par ailleurs, je ne vois pas en quoi l'utilisation de glaive ou épée pour décrire les aléas du soldat romain de l'antiquité a à voir avec le genre de paradoxe temporel explicitement commis par l'auteur. Mais vous trouvez comique (que je crois du moins), et j'ai l'impression que l'humour était malgré tout un des buts de cette tournure, même si l'impression de prédestination de l'Académie aux débordements polémiques des journaux est au final assez bien transmise par ce jeu sur la chronologie. D'une pierre deux coups, en somme... peut-être...

Comment: @Montéedelait : Je peux confirmer! J'adore le sarcasme gratuit. Par principe! +1 pour votre pénultième comm. Le dernier... en revanche de par contre... j'ai rien compris... peut-être se fait-il trop tard hic&nunc de ce côté-ci de l'Atlantique...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86535/discussion-between-montee-de-lait-and-acoswt).

Comment: Le conditionel est simplement le futur du passé dans des phrases comme ça. Mais si **toi** tu penses autrement…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : 1/ Je ne connais pas de conjugaison appelée fdp - 2/ Je n'ai pas indiqué quelle **valeur** il convenait de lui donner.

Comment: Sur l’expression du futur d'un moment passé en utilisant le conditionnel: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel#L'expression_du_futur

Answer (score 1):

L’[hystérologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hyst%C3%A9rologie), ou hystéron-protéron, est une figure de style qui intervertit l’ordre chronologique ou logique des faits qu’elle présente. Plus présente chez les écrivains antiques, elle est souvent mal comprise aujourd’hui, son absurdité étant perçue avec trop d’acuité pour qu’elle puisse préserver son pouvoir d’évocation.

L’idée est de donner la priorité à ce qui importe, de mentionner d’entrée de jeu ce qui compte le plus. Si l’effet est plus important que la cause, ou le postérieur à l’antérieur, alors la cause ou l’événement antérieur sera relégué à une position satellite, en dépit de la chronologie ou de la logique.

Virgile, par exemple, en a fait usage, donnant ici priorité à la mort, inévitable, plutôt qu’au moyen par lequel elle arrivera. Les traductions françaises consultées sont, à une exception près, fidèles au texte latin.

> **Moriamur et in media arma ruamus.**
>       –*Aenidos (L’Énéide)* II.353, Virgile
>
> - *Mourons en nous précipitant au milieu des ennemis.*
>        <sub>Traduction de Th. Cabaret-Dupaty, 1897</sub>
> - *[...] mourons, jetons-nous au milieu des glaives ennemis.*
>        <sub>Traduction d’Aug. Desporte, 1902</sub>
> - *Mourons ! Jetons-nous au milieu des armes.*
>        <sub>Traduction d’André Bellessort, ca. 1964</sub>
> - *Mourons, et jetons-nous au milieu des épées !*
>        <sub>Traduction de Marc Chouet, 1984</sub>
> - *Mourons et au milieu des armes jetons-nous*
>        <sub>Traduction de Jeanne Dion et Philippe Heuzé, 2015</sub>

Une autre hystérologie de Virgile a connu un sort plus malheureux en traduction, où seule une traduction littérale, peu élégante car collant au mot-à-mot, la rend en français.

> **Inclusos utero Danos et pinea furtim**
>   **Laxat claustra Sinon.**
>       –*Aenidos (L’Énéide)* II.258, Virgile
>
> - *Sinon [...] relâche furtivement les Grecs enfermés dans le ventre du cheval et ouvre les clôtures de-pin*
>        <sub>Traduction littérale d’Aug. Desporte, 1902</sub>
> - *Sinon [...] ouvre furtivement la prison des Grecs.*
>        <sub>Traduction de Th. Cabaret-Dupaty, 1897</sub>
> - *Sinon ouvre secrètement aux Grecs la prison de sapin qui les enfermait dans ses flancs.*
>        <sub>Traduction d’Aug. Desporte, 1902</sub>
> - *Sinon [...] se faufile près du monstre où les Grecs étaient enfermés et abaisse les trappes de sapin.*
>        <sub>Traduction d’André Bellessort, ca. 1964</sub>
> - *Sinon [...] ouvre furtivement la trappe en bois de pin*
>     *Et libère les Grecs enfermés dans le monstre.*
>        <sub>Traduction de Marc Chouet, 1984</sub>
> - *[...] un homme [...] libère les Danaens enfermés dans le ventre en ouvrant les panneaux de pin, en cachette : c’est Sinon*
>        <sub>Traduction de Jeanne Dion et Philippe Heuzé, 2015</sub>

Ces réticences sur ce genre de figure de style sont strictement implicites. D’autres furent plus explicites :

> **a preposterous way of speaking, putting that first which should be last.**
>   *une manière de parler absurde, qui met en premier ce qui devrait être en dernier.*
>       <sub>Nathan Bailey, lexicographe anglais du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle</sub>

---

### Des exemples envisageables dans la vie quotidienne ?

Est-il besoin d’être un auteur antique pour trouver une valeur à l’hystéron-protéron ? Ou pour l’utiliser ? Peut-être pas...

- *Je t’ai servi une soupe. Et je l’ai faite aux tomates, comme tu la préfères.*
- *J’ai rendu à ta sœur le livre qu’elle m’avait prêté. Je l’ai beaucoup aimé.*

---

#### Pourquoi Louis-Bernard Robitaille utilisa-t-il l’hystérologie dans cet extrait ?

Si l’auteur semble à ce point indifférent à la chronologie, c’est parce qu’il énonce, en commettant une aussi remarquable erreur de causalité, une vérité intemporelle, qui n’a pas à s’embarrasser de la séquence des évènements. La véritable raison qu’il invoque pour justifier que l’élection de Hugo était une affaire d’État, ce n’est pas le fait que l’élection de Voltaire ou de Maurras en auront été, mais que « dès les origines, [...] l’Académie avait été [...] une affaire d’État majeure. ». Cela fait partie de la fabrique même de son être. Le jour où elle perdra cette particularité, elle ne sera plus l’Académie.